# Change ::selection color for the highlighting on Apple mobile devices?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, selection

So if I want to change the selection on Chrome, Safari and Firefox for computers and android tablets i use this code:

```
::selection {
  background: #33C3F0;
}

::-webkit-selection {
  background: #33C3F0;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #33C3F0;
}
```

But if I look at it on an iPhone and iPad, the highlighting color does not change. As it changes neither in Safari nor Chrome, I'd guess it is not possible system wide on ios mobile devices. I tried -webkit-tap-highlight-color too but that just change the backgroundcolor of the active clicked item like a link.

Examples:

[iPad selection is default apple selection blue instead of the blue un the second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAsEP.png)

[On android Chrome however it is the right blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsA4t.png)

So now, is there any way I could get the text selection highlight color on my website to be another color than default on mobile ios devices?

Comment: Personally, I have not found a way to do this - So if you find out, let us know with an answer

Comment: Old question but I'm running into this too. I wonder if it's some attempt at "user security", trying to control interactions like this. Will post an answer if I find one …